# Creating summary table in r (markdown)

Tags: r, markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to create a table like the one below in R (and then output in Rmarkdown); and there's got to be a way (I'd say easier way, but ultimately, my attempt failed).
[image]

What I tried to do was create four separate datasets and then rbind them, similar to what I'm doing in this reproducible example (below) if I wanted to look at a chart of "vs" (whatever that is) and "gear" as a function of "carb," Ultimately, I get to a place where the first column won't join because one is labelled "vs" and the other is labelled "gear," but really I want to maintain those labels with their observations in the same column (as age, sex, ethnicity, and SES all are).

Thanks!

```r
m <- mtcars%>%
  mutate(vs = ifelse(vs == 1, "one", "zero"))%>%
  group_by(cyl, vs)%>%
  summarize(count = n())%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  spread(cyl, count)

m.g <-  mtcars%>%
  mutate(gear = ifelse(gear == 3, "three", ifelse(
    gear == 4, "four", "five")
    )
  )%>%
  group_by(cyl, gear)%>%
  summarize(count = n())%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  spread(cyl, count)

total.d.f <- rbind(m, m.g)
```

Comment: You could always give each data.frame the same column names: `colnames(m) <- colnames(m.g)` before `rbind`-ing.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but then I won't see the variable names in the table.

Comment: Right, but then you just add a separating row with the labels you want in the "middle" of the table.